# scope var and lifetime into sails controller nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller, sails.js

I use sails.js, I'm wondering baout the scope var and lifetime on a var declared into a sails contoller.

```
var user = {};

module.exports = {
  index: function (req, res) {
    user.connected = false;

    return res.view({
      user: user
    });
  },

  member: function (req, res) {
    user.connected = true;

    return res.view('home/index', {
      user: user
    });

  }
};
```

In first place I tried to set `user` only in the `member` function, but once I visited the /member webpage, the user was initialized with `user.connected=true` and when I visited the /index page it was still connected. So I added the `user.connected=false` into the `index` function and it works like expected.

But I dont understand at all. From what I know, the `user` is a local variable to the `HomeController.js` script, it should be destroyed each time the file is loaded and reset to `{}` at each call.

*Actually, while I wrote the question, I thought about something...*

Because I use a `module.exports`, the functions index and member are loaded into the memory and the call are not done on the `HomeController.js` script but on the `module.exports` global object, and because `user` is an object, he is referenced by "pointer" and it's not a copy but a reference inside each function, so when I made a change on it, it's changed everywhere the reference is used. it's like a global object inside a module, weird.

Am I right? Did I miss something? Do you have more advanced explanation about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with sails, but the problem you'll have here is that every request is going to write a user to that module variable and you'll get all sorts of confusion when handling concurrent requests. The standard way of keeping a variable over the duration of a request is to append it to the request object:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.user) {
            // You'll probably have resolved a user and appended it to req in an
            // Earlier middleware.
            req.user = {};
        }

        user.connected = false;

        res.view({ user: req.user });
    },

    member: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.user) {
            req.user = {};
        }

        user.connected = true;

        res.view('home/index', { user: req.user });
    }
};
```

Comment: Ho, yes, I know that, the fact is that actually this code is temporary, I wrote it to the designer has some variables without having to take care about the database! It's just fake data to create the views, the real data will come after.
It's just that when I created the fake data I wondered about the lifetime and scope of the user var because it didn't act as I expected.